# Doxygen link does not work when defined in one block and used in another

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to define a link in doxygen and then use it in a number of different places in the same file. But unfortunately I found out that the link only works in the same block in which it was defined. According to the markdown site, I should be able to define a link *anywhere* in the document http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link. For instance, when I use this code sample, all links work correctly:

```
///I get 10 times more traffic from [Google] [1] than from [Yahoo] [2] or [MSN] [3].
///  [1]: http://google.com/        "Google"
///  [2]: http://search.yahoo.com/  "Yahoo Search"
///  [3]: http://search.msn.com/    "MSN Search"
```

However, if I break that text into two blocks with empty line, all three links no longer work:

```
///I get 10 times more traffic from [Google] [1] than from [Yahoo] [2] or [MSN] [3].

///  [1]: http://google.com/        "Google"
///  [2]: http://search.yahoo.com/  "Yahoo Search"
///  [3]: http://search.msn.com/    "MSN Search"
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem or is it a design point (which would be rather unfortunate)?

For some other reason the code below does not generate link either while according to this page http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_reflinks this should be valid:

```
/// [google]: http://google.com "Google.com"
/// [google]
```

I am using doxygen 1.8.9.1

Comment: Doxygen interpretation of "anywhere in the document" is anywhere within the same comment block.

Comment: @doxygen Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to define a link once and then use it within different comment blocks to avoid duplication?